# Using delay on a Observable within concatMap doesn't emit any items

Tags: functional-programming, kotlin, reactive-programming, rx-java2

Snippet1 (without `delay` function):

```
Observable.range(1, 10)
            .concatMap {
                Observable.just(it)
            }
            .subscribe{ print(it)}
```

Output : 12345678910

Snippet2 (with `delay` function):

```
Observable.range(1, 10)
            .concatMap {
                Observable.just(it).delay(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            }
            .subscribe{ print(it)}
```

Output : DOESN'T PRINT ANYTHING

Why using a `delay` will result in emitting nothing? I am unable to comprehend what actually is happening here?

Comment: Your second snippet doesn't have a `delay` in it.

Comment: I have updated the snippet. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: You don't wait for it to print it. Please read the [Getting started](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava#simple-background-computation).